# Meaning of "this" for a struct (C#)

Tags: c#

According to MSDN (Section 11.3.6 of the [C# spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc)):

> Within an instance constructor of a
>   struct, `this` corresponds to an `out`
>   parameter of the struct type, and
>   within an instance function member of
>   a struct, `this` corresponds to a `ref`
>   parameter of the struct type. In both
>   cases, `this` is classified as a
>   variable, and it is possible to modify
>   the entire struct for which the
>   function member was invoked by
>   assigning to `this` or by passing `this`
>   as a `ref` or `out` parameter.

I don't get it.  How is `this` different for a struct than for a class?  Code examples are appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eric Lippert had a fabulous [post](http://ericlippert.com/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/) on mutating `readonly struct`s a while back that will really help clarify the issue for you. There's even a code example, and a quiz!

The salient point is that `struct`s obey value semantics and `class`es do not and so `this` must mean something different for the two. `this` is `readonly` for a `class`, but not for a `struct`. The following code is legal

```
struct Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void DoGoTime() {
        GoTime(ref this);
    }

    public static void GoTime(ref Point p) {
        p.x = 100;
        p.y = 100;
    }
}
```

but is not if "`struct`" is replaced by "`class`."

Answer (score 6):

When you're dealing with structs, you're dealing with value types.

In a class, "this" is a reference to the current instance.  This lets you mutate the class instance by setting properties/fields on the class.

However, if you're in a struct, things act differently.  When you're in a struct's method, "this" lets you mutate the struct.  However, if you're using this in a method, you're almost always dealing with a copy of the "original" struct.

For example:

```
struct Test
{
    int i;
    void Mutate() {
         this.i += 1;
    }
}
```

When you use this:

```
void MutateTest(Test instance)
{
    instance.Mutate();
}

{
    Test test = new Test();
    test.i = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(test.i); // Writes 3
    test.Mutate(); // test.i is now 4
    Console.WriteLine(test.i); // Writes 4
    MutateTest(test); // MutateTest works on a copy.. "this" is only part of the copy itself
    Console.WriteLine(test.i); // Writes 4 still
}
```

Now, the stranger part - this is valid, and what that quote was saying:

```
struct Test
{
    public Test(int value)
    {
       this.i = value;
    }
    int i;

    void Mutate(int newValue) {
         this = new Test(newValue); // This wouldn't work with classes
    }
}


///
{
    Test test = new Test();
    test.i = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(test.i); // Writes 3
    test.Mutate(4); 
    Console.WriteLine(test.i); // Writes 4
```

Answer (score 6):

Jason's answer and Eric's post show one aspect of `this` which is interesting... but there's another which is even more alarming:

**You can reassign `this` within a method, even if the type is otherwise immutable.**

To demonstrate it, we'll use a struct which is stored in a *non-readonly* variable, but which contains a readonly field:

```
using System;

public struct LooksImmutable
{
    private readonly int value;
    public int Value { get { return value; } }

    public LooksImmutable(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void GoCrazy()
    {
        this = new LooksImmutable(value + 1);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        LooksImmutable x = new LooksImmutable(5);
        Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
        x.GoCrazy();
        Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I felt a great disturbance in the Force, as if millions of voices suddenly cried out in terror and were calling for const correctness. Please don't show this to my C++ coworkers. :-)

Comment: Eh, const in C++ is a lie. In C++, const often means "I promise to not change this thing", and not "I have a guarantee that this thing is immutable".

Comment: Nice example Jon. Here what you're demonstrating is that though the struct might be immutable, the *variable* that holds the struct is not. That variable can still vary; that's why its called a variable. This is just a particularly awful way of making it vary.